# Get original indices of a sorted Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of distances `a = np.array([20.5 ,5.3 ,60.7 ,3.0 ], 'double')` and I need the indices of the sorted array (for example `[3, 1, 0, 2]`, for `a.sort()`). Is there a function in Numpy to do that?

Comment: Please check out my solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442599/find-positions-of-elements-in-sorted-array/71993234#71993234 not specific to numpy, which also allows reverse (descending) )sort without need for reversing the array after it was sorted, and specification of a `key` function.

Answer (score 57):

Yes, there's the `x = numpy.argsort(a)` function or `x = numpy.ndarray.argsort(a)` method. It does exactly what you're asking for. You can also call `argsort` as a method on an `ndarray` object like so: `a.argsort()`.

Here's a link to the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example, for reference and convenience:

```
# create an array
a = np.array([5,2,3])

# np.sort - returns the array, sorted
np.sort(a)
>>> array([2, 3, 5])

# argsort - returns the original indexes of the sorted array
np.argsort(a)
>>> array([1, 2, 0])
```