# extracting indices from sorted list

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have an unsorted list and you sort it using `np.sort`. Is there a way to get the indices of the sorted list from the original list using numpy?

Comment: Are you looking for `argsort`, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341557/get-original-indices-of-a-sorted-numpy-array)?

Comment: Would you accept an answer using python builtin `sorted`? `args = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]; print sorted((value, index) for index, value in enumerate(args))`

Comment: @DSM I used argsort(). Thanks

Comment: @lord12 If this question is answered to your satisfaction, you should accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer, as per [faq].

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to augment the array with the position indices and then sort the 2-D array.  That gives you both the sorted data and its original position indicies at the same time.

If you only want the indicies (not the sorted data), the use *argsort*:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> arr = array([10, 5, 80, 20, 70, 18])
>>> arr.argsort()
array([1, 0, 5, 3, 4, 2])
```