# Apply argsort per row in array skipping certain elements based on threshold - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, np.argsort

I would like to apply a sort operation, row per row, only keeping values above a given threshold.

For this, I see I can use a masked array to apply the threshold.
However, `argsort` keeps considering masked values (below the threshold) and replace them with a `fill_value`.

However, I simply don't want any result if the value has been replaced with a NaN.

```
a = np.array([[0.522235,0.128270,0.708973],
              [0.994557,0.844426,0.366608],
              [0.986669,0.143659,0.395891],
              [0.291339,0.421843,0.278869],
              [0.250303,0.861475,0.904534],
              [0.973436,0.360466,0.751913]])

threshold = 0.5
m_a = np.ma.masked_less_equal(a, threshold)
argsorted = m_a.argsort(-1)
```

This gives me:

```
array([[0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```

But I would like to get:

```
array([[0,   NaN,   1],
       [1,     0, NaN],
       [0,   NaN, NaN],
       [NaN, NaN, NaN],
       [NaN,   0,   1],
       [  1, NaN,   0]])
```

Any idea to get to this result?

Thanks for your help!
Bests,

Comment: yes, you are right, I am correcting right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add one more `argsort` for an easier way to get to our desired output -

```
sidx = argsorted.argsort(1)
mask = sidx >= (a.shape[1]-m_a.mask.sum(1,keepdims=True))
out = np.where(mask,np.nan,sidx)
```

We can also start from scratch to avoid `masked-arrays` -

```
def thresholded_argsort(a, threshold):
    m = a<threshold
    ac = a.copy()
    ac[m] = ac.max()+1
    sidx = ac.argsort(1).argsort(1)
    mask = sidx>=(ac.shape[1]-m.sum(1,keepdims=True))
    return np.where(mask,np.nan,sidx)
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: a
Out[46]: 
array([[0.522235, 0.12827 , 0.708973],
       [0.994557, 0.844426, 0.366608],
       [0.986669, 0.143659, 0.395891],
       [0.291339, 0.421843, 0.278869],
       [0.250303, 0.861475, 0.904534],
       [0.973436, 0.360466, 0.751913]])

In [47]: thresholded_argsort(a, threshold=0.5)
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0., nan,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0., nan],
       [ 0., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1., nan,  0.]])
```

Note : We can avoid the additional argsort with `array-assignment` for performance using [`argsort_unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442683/). So, for `2D` arrays along second axis, it would be -

```
def argsort_unique2D(idx):
    m,n = idx.shape
    idx_out = np.empty((m,n),dtype=int)
    np.put_along_axis(idx_out, idx, np.arange(n), axis=1)
    return idx_out
```

So, `argsorted.argsort(1)` could be replaced by `argsort_unique2D(argsorted)`, while `ac.argsort(1).argsort(1)` with `argsort_unique2D(ac.argsort(1))` in the earlier posted solutions.

Comment: Hi @Divakar, thanks for your help. I am delving into this direction. Always interested to learn new tricks and get more performant code :). Would you mind elaborating your recipe with `argsort_unique` please? Thanks for your help already!

Comment: @pierre_j Added into post.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. I started to play with your earlier post into which you present `argsort_unique` and encountered indeed trouble with indices. `argsort_unique2D` handles this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you dont want to consider NaN for for the sorting. In that case, I am not sure about the logic behind your expected result. You can try the following code. I believe this is what you are looking for:-

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.522235,0.128270,0.708973],
              [0.994557,0.844426,0.366608],
              [0.986669,0.143659,0.395891],
              [0.291339,0.421843,0.278869],
              [0.250303,0.861475,0.904534],
              [0.973436,0.360466,0.751913]])

threshold = 0.5
m_a = np.ma.masked_less_equal(a, threshold).filled(np.nan)
result = np.where(
        np.isnan(m_a),
        np.nan, m_a.argsort(-1)
    )
result
```

It should give you the following result :-

```
array([[ 0., nan,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0., nan],
       [ 0., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2., nan,  1.]])
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The last row doesn't seem to match.

Comment: I dont understand the logic behind 3rd to last row in the expected result.

Comment: AFAIU, the indices are to be 0...n in sequence for all above threshold elements.

Comment: Not considering NaN for sorting should not change the indices of the elements IMO.

Comment: @TuhinSharma Thanks for your help. But I don't get also the logic behind the 3rd row. I can understand it should be possible to devise a function that keeps the index before filtering the NaN. But then this logic should apply to the 3 first rows as well. So either you filter nan after sorting, in which case indices start at 2 in descending order (the case we meet in your example at rows 5 and 6) or filtering is made before sorting, and with indices starting at 0 in ascending order, and this is the first rows of the example. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = np.array([[0.522235,0.128270,0.708973],
              [0.994557,0.844426,0.366608],
              [0.986669,0.143659,0.395891],
              [0.291339,0.421843,0.278869],
              [0.250303,0.861475,0.904534],
              [0.973436,0.360466,0.751913]])

threshold = .5


def tri(ligne):
    s = sorted(ligne, key=lambda x: x < threshold and float('inf') or x)
    nv_liste = [s.index(v) for v in ligne]
    for i in range(len(ligne)):
        if ligne[i] < threshold:
            nv_liste[i] = np.nan
    return nv_liste

np.apply_along_axis(tri, 1, a)
```

gives you:

```py
array([[ 0., nan,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0., nan],
       [ 0., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1., nan,  0.]])
```

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for your help. Comparing your proposal to that of Divakar, it is about ~80 times slower. On a 100k array, this starts to be visible ;) . Thanks nonetheless!